# IIS issues challenge on unprotected folders

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-7.5

We've encountered an issue where IIS issues a challenge for all directories on the site, including the ones which are marked to allow anonymous users. This only happens when accessing the site through HTTPS.

The directory structure is similar to this:

```
  /
  +--secure
  +--unsecure
```

The root folder is configured so all users are authorized, both anonymous and digest authentication are enabled.
The "secure" folder is configured so that anonymous users are denied.

Initially, IIS issues a challenge to Firefox, regardless of the directory. IE and Chrome only receive challenges in the "secure" directory.

After logging out from the client machine and logging back in, only IE experiences the expected behavior, Chrome and Firefox receive challenges in all directories.

One other possibly relevant detail. The server where this occurs uses a subdomain, so the URL is www.dev.mydomain.com, but the wildcard SSL certificate is issued to *.mydomain.com.  Using a self-signed certificate on another server, we can't duplicate the problem.

**Update:** We've discovered that turning off the default document causes the problem to go away (re-enabling causes it to return). It's a workaround, but we'd prefer to know the true cause.  This has the scent of an IIS bug combined with IE knowing some "secret handshake" the other browsers don't.

Comment: Check the file rights on the unsecure folder (so that the user running the app pool has access to it)

Comment: @AndersBornholm - I neglected another detail. The challenges on the unprotected paths only occur with https.  Accessing the site over port 80 only gets challenges on the secure directory.  Would https be associated with a different user?

Comment: Ah... Then I got nothing ;-)

Comment: Check the rights on that default document -- the file itself could have some permissions attached.

Comment: @WyattBarnett, The challenge occurs when the user attempts to access **any** unprotected document (not sure anything even exists with one of the default names). For a permissions issue, I'd expect the challenge to occur regardless of HTTPS.

Comment: Ah, didn't read you right the first time. One other thing -- turn on the IIS detailed tracing, it should show what is issuing the challenge. If IE and Chrome are silently handling it then it sounds like you've got windows auth in play.

Comment: Windows authentication is disabled, and once the user logs out and back in on the client machine, Chrome and Firefox both see the same behavior. Turning on the detailed tracing might be worth a shot, though we're not really seeing anything particularly revealing in the various browsers' network tools.